# Getting data from cell

Tags: php, mysql, row, cell

I have a database table called "settings", and in that table I've got 2 columns. Example picture:

[image]

As you can see, the first columns is called "**setting_name**" and the second is called "**setting_value**".

**How can I do, so whenever I write example:**

```
echo $setting['ad_cost_micro'];
```

It will print out:

```
0.00200
```

Btw. is it possible to do without a **while** statement?

Comment: screenshot doesnt work, try uploading to tiny pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use PDO, and `fetchAll()`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `setting_name`, `setting_value` FROM `settings`');
$stmt->execute();
$setting = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo $settings['ad_cost_micro']; //Should output 0.00200.
```

Note: Regardless of what you use, **a while loop is unavoidable** because you HAVE to loop through the result set (`fetchAll()`) does that too, also, know that every loop is a while loop (even for loops!).

Comment: Thanks for that information, I wasn't aware of that!

How can I use the above code snippit, so the $setting variable is accessible on all my pages?

Comment: You could store it in a session, or include this bit of code (using `include_once()` or `require_once()` on every page.

Comment: But, what about the $db variable. Can't we leave that out, since it gives me an error.

Comment: Of course, this snippet assumes you have already connected and set up the PDO object. See the [PHP Manual](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) For additional help

Answer (score 1):

if mysqli is available...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(hostname, username, password, database);
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT setting_name,setting_value FROM settings');

if ($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    $rows = $result->fetch_array();
    $setting = array();
    for($i = 0; $i <= $result->num_rows(); $i++)
    {
        $setting[$rows[$i]['setting_name']] = $row[$i]['setting_value'];
    }

    unset($rows);
    $result->free();
}
else
{
    // error handling
}

$mysqli->close();
```

EDIT: removed while in place of for

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the screenshot but maybe...

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $setting[$row['setting_name']] = $row['setting_value'];
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but this is done in a while loop. Can't this be avoided?

Comment: @Rikudo What's wrong with that? We know nothing about the OP's installation, so you don't know whether or not other functions (eg: mysqli, PDO) are available.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are (unofficially) deprecated. Much better alternatives exists such as MySQLi (Good) or PDO (Great).

Comment: They certainly are not deprecated and probably will never be due to 80% of codebases still using `mysql` functions. But thanks for the criticism :-/